# Unable to locate element in Selenium-java by xpathe

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I can't select the button to click.

I tried

```
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Follow']")).click();
```

Here is my html:

```
<tr>
<td>click</td>
<td>//div[@id='root']/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[6]/figure/button</td>
<td></td>
```

Here is the button Image:
[image]

Please help me.

Comment: Where is the `div` with text `Follow`? There are just two table cells on provide piece of source code: one with text `"click"` and second with XPath... Can you share exact HTML?

Comment: the HTML recorded by selenium IDE. & the button contain the text Follow. @Andersson

Comment: here is the HTML inspection by firebug before click the button `code`<button class="btn btn-default user-card-follow" data-reactid="1177">`code` & the HTML after click the button `code`<button class="btn btn-default user-card-follow is-active" data-reactid="1177"><span data-reactid="1178">Followed</span></button>`code`

Comment: As per provided in comments piece of `HTML` text is "Followed", but not "Follow"... try `//button[span='Followed']`

Comment: But need to click on 'Follow' this button `<button class="btn btn-default user-card-follow" data-reactid="1177">` not this button `<button class="btn btn-default user-card-follow is-active" data-reactid="1177"><span data-reactid="1178">Followed</span></button>`